# I would like to install windows 7 on ubuntu 12.04 on a mac 8.1 hard drive

Tags: windows-7

I am trying to install windows 7 on ubuntu 12.4. Can you walk me through this process. My ubuntu is installed on a Mac 8.1.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you talking about Mac OS 8.1 or Mac OS X (10.8.1) Mountain Lion?  Are you trying to dual boot your Mac with Mac OS and Ubuntu 12.4 or just boot Ubuntu 12.4?  Or are you running Ubuntu 12.04 in a virtual machine under Mac OS? Are you trying to run Windows 7 in a virtual machine under Ubuntu 12.4?

Answer (score 1):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation has a full run down.

Basically, be careful, but.

1. Resize your dmac partition with Disk utility
2. Install Bootcamp and windows, make sure to leave enough space for linux
3. Install Linux
4. Fix the boot loader issues.

You  can also find a wealth of information here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro

If your just trying for Ubuntu and Windows with no OS X, then just proceed normally. Re-size your disk, then install windows, fix boot issues that arise.